# Tests - How to show test error messages in lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

I want to view the request error messages to find out what the error was.

I return a 'message' parameter, with the value of the error variable that trycatch generates. I just can't figure out how to show this when I run the tests

ColumnController

```php
public function store(ColumnPostRequest $request): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
{
    try {
        $column = Column::create($request->all());

        return response()->json(['data' => new ColumnResource($column)], 201);
    } catch (\Exception $error) {
        return response()->json(['message' => $error], 500);
    }
}
```

ColumnTest - store

```
public function testStoreColumnSuccess()
{
    $parameters = [
        'row_id' => 4,
        'label' => 'Label do campo',
        'column_type' => 'text',
        'tip' => 'Dica do campo',
        'size' => 1,
        'situation' => true
    ];

    $this->post('/columns', $parameters, []);

    $this->seeStatusCode(201);
    $this->seeJsonStructure([
        'data' => [
            'id',
            'row_id',
            'label',
            'column_type',
            'tip',
            'size',
            'situation'
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to cause an error first. An issue I see is you're catching a generic `\Exception` instead of something specific, which tells me you probably put that try catch as redundancy. What are you hoping to catch there?

#### Or in other words, what **can** go wrong with these two lines?

```php
$column = Column::create($request->all());

return response()->json(['data' => new ColumnResource($column)], 201);
```

---

Can `Column::create($request->all())` cause a constraint violation such as..

1. Not null constraint violation?
2. Unique constraint violation?
3. Foreign key constraint violation?

If it can, then you haven't added enough validation rules in `ColumnPostRequest` (and also you should use `$request->validated()` when using a Form Request).

---

Can `new ColumnResource($column)` cause an exception somehow? If so, it seems there is a problem in your implementation that you need to fix, rather than trying to catch an `\Exception`.

---

What you **can** do however, is causing a `ValidationException` triggered by your `ColumnPostRequest`.

```php
public function store(ColumnPostRequest $request): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
{
    $column = Column::create($request->all());

    return response()->json(['data' => new ColumnResource($column)], 201);
}
```

```php
protected $valid_parameters = [
    'row_id' => 4,
    'label' => 'Label do campo',
    'column_type' => 'text',
    'tip' => 'Dica do campo',
    'size' => 1,
    'situation' => true
];

public function testRowIdMustBeANumber()
{
    $parameters = $this->valid_parameters;
    $parameters['row_id'] = 'something invalid';

    $response = $this->post('/columns', $parameters, []);

    $response->assertJsonValidationErrors('row_id', $responseKey = null);
}

public function testRowIdIsRequired()
{
    $parameters = $this->valid_parameters;
    unset($parameters['row_id'];

    $response = $this->post('/columns', $parameters, []);

    $response->assertJsonValidationErrors('row_id', $responseKey = null);
}

// repeat for every validation rule
```

[Lumen 10.x - Testing - Application Testing](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/10.x/testing#application-testing)